# Calendar implementation on swift

Tags: ios, jtapplecalendar

I am working on calendar implementation.

I want current and past dates to be selectable, but not future dates, as my application only requires current and past dates.

How do I disable the selection of future dates in a calendar?

Comment: check maximumdate when you select date in calendar

Comment: Which calendar library you are using?

Comment: CalendarPopUp - JTAppleCalendar library

Comment: @JitendraModi Thank You

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava Thank You

Answer (score 2):

When a date is selected the JTAppleCalender view's delegate method `didSelectDate` will be getting called.

So you could handle your date selection inside this method like,

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
        if date == currentDate || date == previousDate {
           //do your logic here
        }
        else {
          return
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to remove 3 months limit?

Comment: Also i want disable future date.

Comment: @AshuDesigner In JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate's `configureCalendar` function you can set the `ConfigurationParameters` where you can configure the start and end date

Comment: @Arvind A R Thank You

Comment: Yes it is working fine but i have one more issue. I am working On JTAppleCalendar library, I have Set calendar on Both textboxes like FROM - TO Search.

I want,like example FROM textbox have selected 3 january 2017 and second calander textbox have should be enable only 3 january -2017 to 7 sep 2017 current date

Comment: @AshuDesigner if its working fine it would be great if you could accept the answer so that it will be helpful to others too.

Comment: var components = DateComponents()
        components.year = -100
        let minDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date())        
        components.year = 100
        let maxDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date())